# How do I duplicate a dictionary element and re add it back with a key and value change

Tags: python

```
dict1 = {"top":{"left":[100],"right":[100],"down":[200]}}

dict2 = {"top1":{"left":[100],"right":[100],"down":[200]},"top2":{"left":[100],"right":[100],"down":[300]}}
```

Above are two dictionaries, the first being the starting and the bottom being the final. I want to duplicate the first one's values and then re-add them with a new key name and the down having 100 added to it. The final product should look like the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) so that each item has unique lists, rather than sharing them between all the items. We loop twice, to add two copies to `dict2`.

```
import copy

dict1 = {"top":{"left":[100],"right":[100],"down":[200]}}

dict2 = {}

for i in range(2):
    # make a copy of {"left":[100],"right":[100],"down":[200]}
    # We need to use deepcopy so that we get new lists, rather
    # than references to the same ones each time. (otherwise,
    # changing one would change all the others)
    new_object = copy.deepcopy(dict1["top"])

    # we need to alter the 0th index of the list of "down"
    new_object["down"][0] += 100 * i

    # come up with a new dict key for our object
    #  - using i+1 so we get top1, top2 instead of top0, top1
    name = f"top{i+1}"
    dict2[name] = new_object
```

```
>>> dict2
dict2
{'top1': {'left': [100], 'right': [100], 'down': [200]}, 'top2': {'left': [100], 'right': [100], 'down': [300]}}
```